# Do calculation dynamically when inputting the numbers in corresponding row - Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

There are `m students` and `n criteria` columns in a student row and a total column in the same row. But the total has to be calculated dynamically when inputting the numbers in corresponding row only. what all modifications needed? In this manner, all the inputs in the first row are summed up. But only row-wise summing needed.

```
<script>
    var num=[];
    function recalculate(rowData,studCode) {        
        var n = document.getElementById('criteria_count').value;    
        num.push(parseFloat(document.getElementById('criteria_mark_'+rowData).value));
        var total=0;

        for (var i = 0; i <n; i++) {
            total = total + parseFloat(num[i]) ;
            if (!isNaN(total)) {
                document.getElementById('total_mark_'+studCode).value = Math.round(total);
            }
        }      
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You should be iterating over each row for the specified column, your for loop doesn't represent this. The for loop conditional statement says i < criteria_count , I can't see the variable criteria_count anywhere. What value does it hold and how is it calculated?

Comment: n is criteria_count. I corrected that now. But still problem is there.

Comment: You're now casting the .value of criteria_count to float, I'm not entirely sure you want to use a float in your conditional statement, do you?

Comment: @D.Foley No..float not needed.. I removed casting.

Comment: Okay, you're calling this subroutine on the event onchange ?

Comment: onkeypress() and onblur()

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I understand your requirements correctly. I made a JSFiddle detailing how to achieve what you have explained (assuming I understood you correctly).

https://jsfiddle.net/z0d4y8ao/12/

This is looking through each  on the specified row, and is calculating the total and putting it separately into a  result element.

If you use this code keep in mind that it is raw javascript and that you will have to find the result  yourself so you can insert the total value, (personally I create unique ID's with the server side language.).

```
function calcNewVal(rowID)
{
    var row = document.getElementById(rowID);
    var tdCount = row.childElementCount - 1;
    var total = 0;
    var currentTd = null;

    var resultText = document.getElementById('result0');

    for(var i = 0; i < tdCount; i++)
    {
        currentTd = row.children[i].childNodes[0].value;
        total += parseInt(currentTd);
    }

    console.log(total);

    resultText.innerHTML = total;
}
```

the html:

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
    <th>Subject1</th>
    <th>Subject2</th>
    <th>Subject3</th>
    <th>Result</th>
</tr>
<tr onchange="calcNewVal(this.id)" id="row0">
    <td><input type="text" value="13"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="13"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="13"></td>
    <td id="result0"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="row1">
    <td><input type="text" value="13"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="13"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="13"></td>
    <td id="result1"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: _currentTd = row.children[i].childNodes[0].value;_ shows undefined.